# Plotting the AUC from an xgboost model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost, auc

I am currently following the slides from the following [link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-who-is-more-influential-in-a-social-network/data). I am on slide 121/128 and I would like to know how to replicate the AUC. The author did not explain how to do so (the same on slide 124 also). Secondly on slide 125 the following code is produced;

```
bestRound = which.max(as.matrix(cv.res)[,3]-as.matrix(cv.res)[,4])
bestRound
```

I receive the following error;

> Error in as.matrix(cv.res)[, 2] : subscript out of bounds

The data for the following code can be downloaded from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-who-is-more-influential-in-a-social-network/data) and I have produced the code below for your reference.

Question: How can I produce the AUC as the author and why is the subscript out of bounds?

----- Code ------

```
# Kaggle Winning Solutions

train <- read.csv('train.csv', header = TRUE)
test <- read.csv('test.csv', header = TRUE)
y <- train[, 1]
train <- as.matrix(train[, -1])
test <- as.matrix(test)

train[1, ]

#We want to determin who is more influencial than the other

new.train <- cbind(train[, 12:22], train[, 1:11])
train = rbind(train, new.train)
y <- c(y, 1 - y)

x <- rbind(train, test)

(dat[,i]+lambda)/(dat[,j]+lambda)

A.follow.ratio = calcRatio(x,1,2)
A.mention.ratio = calcRatio(x,4,6)
A.retweet.ratio = calcRatio(x,5,7)
A.follow.post = calcRatio(x,1,8)
A.mention.post = calcRatio(x,4,8)
A.retweet.post = calcRatio(x,5,8)
B.follow.ratio = calcRatio(x,12,13)
B.mention.ratio = calcRatio(x,15,17)
B.retweet.ratio = calcRatio(x,16,18)
B.follow.post = calcRatio(x,12,19)
B.mention.post = calcRatio(x,15,19)
B.retweet.post = calcRatio(x,16,19)

x = cbind(x[,1:11],
          A.follow.ratio,A.mention.ratio,A.retweet.ratio,
          A.follow.post,A.mention.post,A.retweet.post,
          x[,12:22],
          B.follow.ratio,B.mention.ratio,B.retweet.ratio,
          B.follow.post,B.mention.post,B.retweet.post)

AB.diff = x[,1:17]-x[,18:34]
x = cbind(x,AB.diff)
train = x[1:nrow(train),]
test = x[-(1:nrow(train)),]

set.seed(1024)
cv.res <- xgb.cv(data = train, nfold = 3, label = y, nrounds = 100, verbose = FALSE,
                 objective = 'binary:logistic', eval_metric = 'auc')
```

## **Plot the AUC graph here**

```
set.seed(1024)
cv.res = xgb.cv(data = train, nfold = 3, label = y, nrounds = 3000,
                objective='binary:logistic', eval_metric = 'auc',
                eta = 0.005, gamma = 1,lambda = 3, nthread = 8,
                max_depth = 4, min_child_weight = 1, verbose = F,
                subsample = 0.8,colsample_bytree = 0.8)
```

## **Here is the break in the code I come across**

```
#bestRound: -  subscript out of bounds

bestRound <- which.max(as.matrix(cv.res)[,3]-as.matrix(cv.res)[,4])
bestRound
cv.res

cv.res[bestRound,]

set.seed(1024) bst <- xgboost(data = train, label = y, nrounds = 3000,
                             objective='binary:logistic', eval_metric = 'auc',
                             eta = 0.005, gamma = 1,lambda = 3, nthread = 8,
                             max_depth = 4, min_child_weight = 1,
                             subsample = 0.8,colsample_bytree = 0.8)
preds <- predict(bst,test,ntreelimit = bestRound)

result <- data.frame(Id = 1:nrow(test), Choice = preds)
write.csv(result,'submission.csv',quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many parts of the code have little sense to me but here is a minimal example of building a model with the provided data:

Data:

```
train <- read.csv('train.csv', header = TRUE)
y <- train[, 1]
train <- as.matrix(train[, -1])
```

Model:

```
library(xgboost)
cv.res <- xgb.cv(data = train, nfold = 3, label = y, nrounds = 100, verbose = FALSE,
                 objective = 'binary:logistic', eval_metric = 'auc', prediction = T)
```

To obtain cross validation predictions one must specify `prediction = T` when calling `xgb.cv`.

To obtain best iteration:

```
it = which.max(cv.res$evaluation_log$test_auc_mean)
best.iter = cv.res$evaluation_log$iter[it]
```

to plot ROC curve on the cross validation results:

```
library(pROC)
plot(pROC::roc(response = y,
               predictor = cv.res$pred,
               levels=c(0, 1)),
     lwd=1.5)
```

[image]

To get a confusion matrix (assuming 0.5 prob is the threshold):

```
library(caret)
confusionMatrix(ifelse(cv.res$pred <= 0.5, 0, 1), y)
#output
          Reference
Prediction    0    1
         0 2020  638
         1  678 2164

               Accuracy : 0.7607         
                 95% CI : (0.7492, 0.772)
    No Information Rate : 0.5095         
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : <2e-16         

                  Kappa : 0.5212         
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.2823         

            Sensitivity : 0.7487         
            Specificity : 0.7723         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7600         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.7614         
             Prevalence : 0.4905         
         Detection Rate : 0.3673         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.4833         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7605         

       'Positive' Class : 0
```

That being said one should aim to tune the hyper-parameters with cross validation such as eta, gamma, lambda, subsample, colsample_bytree, colsample_bylevel etc.

The easiest way is to construct a grid search where you use `expand.grid` on all combinations of hyper-parameters and use lapply on the grid with `xgb.cv` as a part of the custom function). If you need more detail please comment.

Comment: Thank you the AUC plot worked.
"To obtain cross validation predictions one must specify prediction = T when calling xgb.cv" was where I was going wrong.

Comment: Another point I would like to try to replicate was on slide 121/128 the author states "We can see the trend of AUC on training and test sets." How can I go about replicating this on the test set? and what is the purpose of replicating this on the test set?

Comment: @user113156 There is much more to training xgboost models then this. And people have preferences in the way they do things. Generally hyper parameters, data transformations, up/down sampling, variable selection, probability threshold optimization, cost function selection are performed during cross validation. Usually not just one repetition of CV but for instance 5 repetitions of 3-4 fold CV. And when you pick up the best set of all these things you train a model with all the train data and validate on the test set. This is all done to avoid over-fitting.

Comment: When you test 1000s of parameters in CV even tho you train on some data and verify on held out data you are bound to pick the best parameters for the held out data (in fact you are doing just that), so one needs to retest on unseen data again (hence the validation part). To do so, build a model with chosen parameters and the function `xgboost`. Perform prediction on test data with `probability = T` and use the same code for AUC specifying `response = test$y, predictor = pred' assuming pred is the vector with predicted probabilities on the test set.